# Dubbio su "farne"

Tags: grammar

Mentre stavo guardando il film Interstellar ho sentito una frase che mi suonava strana. Nel film, dopo aver fatto atterrare il drone, la figlia ha chiesto al padre "Cosa pensi di farne?" Io pensavo che in questo caso si dovesse usare "farci" invece di "farne". Sicuramente il film non ha commesso errori grammaticali ma vorrei conoscere i vostri chiarimenti in merito, vorrei sapere che funzione svolge quel "ne" in questa frase. Grazie mille a tutti quelli che mi risponderanno.

P.S.
Sì, aggiungo un po' di contesto: 
Figlia: Che cosa pensi di farne? 
Padre: Gli darò da fare qualcosa di socialmente utile...come guidare una mietitrebbia.
Figlia: Non possiamo lasciarlo andare? Non faceva del male a nessuno.
Padre: Deve imparare ad adattarsi, Murph...come tutti noi.

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE! Per poter valutare la tua frase, bisognerebbe conoscere il contesto in cui è stata pronunciata. Potresti aggiungerlo al tuo post, per favore?

Comment: Grazie, ho aggiunto un po' di contesto.

Comment: Allora, a quanto pare, parlano di qualcuno. "Che cosa pensi di farne" starebbe per "Che cosa pensi di [fare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2/) di questa persona".

Comment: No, il "ne" si riferisce al drone.

Comment: Ma il concetto è questo, grazie. Non sapevo che "ne" potesse significare "di ciò" come a volte succede con "ci".

Answer (score 4):

Direi che siano corrette entrambe le frasi: la particella “ci” ha, oltre a molti altri, il senso di “a ciò, su ciò” etc. (cf. https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/), mentre “ne” significa più specificamente “di ciò” (cf. https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ne1/). Poi, nello specifico, bisognerebbe vedere com'era il testo originale e se i personaggi parlano di  fare qualcosa del drone, al drone o che altro.

In più, “ne” viene qualche volta percepito come più elegante o ricercato rispetto a “ci”.

Comment: Ora ho capito tutto! Ho imparato delle cose importanti grazie a te! GRAZIE!

Answer (score 0):

Non ho guardato il film, la figlia vuole chiedere al padre cosa vuole fare *con* il drone? In questo caso "farne" mi sembra corretto. <strike>Con "cosa pensi di farci" chiederebbe cosa il padre vuole fare più generalmente, non riferirendosi specialmente al drone.</strike> ← vedi commenti

Comment: Attenzione: forse hai in mente espressioni come “Che vuoi farci”, che si riferiscono a una situazione generale, ma la particella “ci” ha anche il senso di “a ciò, su ciò” per riferirsi a qualcosa di specifico.

Comment: @DaG Grazie per averla resa accurata, le due voci di Treccani mi erano molto plausibili.

Comment: Grazie comunque della gentile risposta.